# How to change the text of a context using antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How can I change the text of a rule when entering it?

**Example**: I define a rule called `name` in my grammar file, then I want to change the text of rule `name` to `name.getText + "some string"` everytime enter func `enterName`, how to do that?

**Goal**:
*input*: `my name is peter`
*output*: `my name is peterAAAAAAA`

Can I manage this by adding a child to the node?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do that is to concatenate the text you get from your tree plus the text you want to add to it.
Example: in javascript;

```
Listener.prototype.exitSetVar = function (ctx) 
{
var a= ctx.getText();
var b= "any_string";
var x= a+b;
this.stack.push(x);
};
```

OR you can even get a specific node from the tree generated by antlr function for a specific rule. ctx.ID(); or ctx.STRING(); or ctx.INT(); etc. Depends on the tokens you have for a specific rule in your grammar.
Example:

```
Listener.prototype.exitSetVar = function (ctx) 
{
var a= ctx.TOKEN_NAME();
var b= "any_string";
var x= a+b;
this.stack.push(x);
};
```